# Is 你看看自己 correct for daily common speaking in Mandarin language?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Is `你看看自己` correct for daily common speaking in Mandarin language?

or people can understand it but they don't say it that way and better say `你看看你`?

Comment: Maybe you could put the context you're going for, that might help get better suited answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, and both have similar meaning. These two phrases could be used to blame on someone for something.

E.g.

你看看自己這副無精打采還病懨懨的樣子, 誰看了都討厭。

你看看你, 跟你說不要亂碰你還碰, 結果現在果然受傷了吧。